# How to style WP Contact Form 7 Plugin Form using materialize css and Own stylesheet?

Tags: css, wordpress, materialize, contact-form-7

I my website I am using WordPress Contact Form 7 to get some information from my users. The website is built using materialize css Framework.

Now I want to use my custom css style and materialize css style to the form. So that I am using following code. But Its not styling.

Anybody tell me how can I style this form ?

```
<div class="row">
<form class="col s12">
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s6">
<i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
[email* your-email id:icon_prefix class:validate]
<label for="icon_prefix">Your Email</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i modify the same solution as @user7346350 for work taxtarea and icon focus too

```
 $('input').focus(function(e) {
var name = $(this).attr('id');
if ($('label[for="'+name+'"]').length > 0) { 
    $('label[for="'+name+'"]').addClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings('i').addClass('active');
}});

$('input').blur(function(e) {
var name = $(this).attr('id');
if ($('label[for="'+name+'"]').length > 0) { 
    $('label[for="'+name+'"]').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings('i').removeClass('active');
}});

$('textarea').focus(function(e) {
var name = $(this).attr('id');
if ($('label[for="'+name+'"]').length > 0) { 
    $('label[for="'+name+'"]').addClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings('i').addClass('active');
}});

$('textarea').blur(function(e) {
var name = $(this).attr('id');
if ($('label[for="'+name+'"]').length > 0) { 
    $('label[for="'+name+'"]').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings('i').removeClass('active');
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently on a project. I was able to keep the style of materialize in the form by adding this jquery code to my js file:

```
$('input').focus(function(e) {
var name = $(this).attr('name');
if ($('label[for="'+name+'"]').length > 0) { 
    $('label[for="'+name+'"]').addClass('active');
}});

$('input').blur(function(e) {
var name = $(this).attr('name');
if ($('label[for="'+name+'"]').length > 0) { 
    $('label[for="'+name+'"]').removeClass('active');
}});
```

What this code does is to add the class 'active' to the label of the text field that is focused and remove it when it is blurred. So, your code is correct. Just add this snippet add you will have the transition in the text field too.

The reason that you have this problem is due to a wrapper span element that contact form 7 adds as parent of your email field.